# Azure virtual machine in Logical App is not working (InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to make a Logic app to automatically enable my virtual machine in Azure. But I get a strange error on startup, searching the internet didn't help me find a solution.
Azure virtual machine in Logical App is not working (InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant)
I'm trying to make a Logic app to automatically enable my virtual machine in Azure. But I get a strange error on startup, searching the internet didn't help me find a solution.
I want my virtual machine to turn on once a day and then turn off. I only have one virtual machine.

```
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant",
    "message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/aaa/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/aaa' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
```

'https://login.windows.net/aaa' - where aaa is my account, i haven't another accounts.
'https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/' - AppOwnerTenantID.

When I manually start up the machine will start.

And i use my blabla@gmail.com account where my vm, i need to use blabla@company.com account? But i have't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add role assignment in virtual machine resource using Access Control for the logic app.

Also if you are using different tenants then you need to select below while creating app registration.
[image]

- I have tried to start vm using logic app with active directory authentication but I also faced same issue as I did not add role assignment for logic app in virtual machine access control.
  Http request in logic app:
  [image]

Failed run for Http request:

[image]

- As I don't have required access for adding role assignments I could not proceed further. So, you need to add role assignment in virtual machine resource using Access Control for the logic app.
- Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/405123/azure-logic-app-azure-vm-connector-invalidauthenti) which is similar to your issue.
- One of the alternative approach is changing authentication type to system managed identity from AAD oauth.
- Also you can use inbuilt actions in logic app to start and stop VM.
  [image]
- I have tested and it is working as expected,
  [image]
  Reference MS document [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#configure-role-assignments-for-the-vm)